How to use AzureOpenai instance model inside RAGAS - [ not langchain]
I  am having these secrets and this is how I use gpt-4o model:
from ragas import SingleTurnSample 
from ragas.metrics import ResponseRelevancy
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from ragas import evaluate
import requests

To get the secret key/Tokens
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
data = {
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'scope': 'openid email profile'
        }
       
response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers, data=data)
dict_of_response_text = response.json()
token = dict_of_response_text.get("access_token")

To see if model is working
client = AzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint = params["azure_endpoint"], 
  api_key=token,  
  api_version=params["api_version"]
)

response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model=params["model"], # model = "deployment_name".
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Does Azure OpenAI support customer managed keys?"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "Yes, customer managed keys are supported by Azure OpenAI."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Do other Azure AI services support this too?"}
    ],
 temperature=params["temperature"],
 # top_p=params["top_p"],
 max_tokens=params["max_tokens"]
    
)


I'm not using any langchain based famework.
Then I use this example to run:
https://docs.ragas.io/en/stable/concepts/metrics/available_metrics/answer_relevance/#response-relevancy
from ragas import SingleTurnSample 
from ragas.metrics import ResponseRelevancy

sample = SingleTurnSample(
        user_input="When was the first super bowl?",
        response="The first superbowl was held on Jan 15, 1967",
        retrieved_contexts=[
            "The First AFL–NFL World Championship Game was an American football game played on January 15, 1967, at the Los Angeles Memorial Coliseum in Los Angeles."
        ]
    )

scorer = ResponseRelevancy(llm=client)
await scorer.single_turn_ascore(sample)

Throws error:
AttributeError: 'AzureOpenAI' object has no attribute 'generate'
So, how can I pass the instance inside ragas using the information I have above.
